Behaviour of MySQL 5.7 on Craft 5
The recommended MySQL version for Craft 5 is 8.0.17+, but it appears to work with 5.7.
How does this version (5.7) affect site construction and functionality?
We understand that as long as it is not recommended, its introduction should be avoided...


It's not that it’s not recommended, it’s not supported at all. https://craftcms.com/docs/5.x/requirements.html#minimum-system-specs
MySQL 5.7 doesn’t have many of the features that Craft 5 requires to operate successfully (specifically around native JSON column data types and support, but many other areas).
Would not recommend.

Ah,sorry, i misspoke, not recommended, but unsupported.
The cp screen appeared to work fine, so the question was asked with the aim of checking what specific problems it could lead to.

native JSON column data types
These are the parts I understand.

